# How to send mails with some functionality using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am new to Google Apps Script. I have a sheet that collects some "Order Number" from form submit. I want to send mails through an event (On form submit) from my spreadsheet. The form will serve an order number. **When the form is submitted, it will match the older submitted order numbers throughout the whole column. If it got matched once, the mail won't be sent. If it doesn't match then it will send a mail to the email address next to the order number.**

The email address will come from another sheet on the same spreadsheet using VLOOKUP. I managed to do this.
Sorry if I make any mistake with my English.

**Edit:**
I tried  `map()` ,  `filter()` , `indexOf()` these methods. But I too new with this.

```
function search(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy of orderStatus");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow() - 1;  
  var keyword = ss.getRange("H5").getValue();
  var dataSource = ss.getRange(2, 2, lr, 1).getValues();
  
  var mapped = dataSource.map(function(r){ 
                                         return r[0]});  
  
  var showPos = mapped.indexOf(keyword) + 2;
  
  var getMail = ss.getRange(showPos, 4).getValue();
  
  var filted = mapped.filter(filterlogic);  

}

var filterlogic = function(r){
  if(r !== "zil20200010"){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Show your script. Provide [mcve]

Comment: I need to see your script. *I tried  map() ,  filter() , indexOf() these methods.* Show that. Show what you've tried. [Edit] to show your script.

Comment: @TheMaster I have added my code here. I was testing these methods. I am new with javascript too.

Comment: Can you add this line `console.log(JSON.stringify(ss))` after the `var ss = ...` and show the content of `ss` in your question.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit You get a event object, if you get a trigger, which can be used to find the actual line data that is submitted now. [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+onFormSubmit*+spreadsheet+is%3Aa) for samples. Also see [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: @TheMaster can I take the newly submitted data and search that new data in whole column excluding that last/new submitted row?

Comment: Sure. You can do anything. See [arrays guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Comment: @TheMaster I got my problem solved. What should I do next? shall I add an answer here? or edit my post above?

Comment: You can add a answer. See [answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to all of you who helped me to reach this point. I found the solution to my problem after some "trial and error". I wanted to limit sending emails.

This code takes the Range. Get its values in an array. I mapped that array to act as a string. Then I added `.pop()` to that string, it removes our last/newly submitted data in that range. Then I used `.includes()` method to search my value in the mapped array, and assigned it to a variable called final (just came to my mind). This variable returns true/false depending on search results. If the order number does not exist then it returns false. After that, we set an if statement to execute our mailing function. If our order number does not match and return final as false our mailing function happens. Else it does nothing (means no email sents). And that's it!

**Here is the code that solved my problem**

```
function orderStatus(e) {
  try {
    
    var theirMail, subject, message;
    var ourName, theirName;
    var sSheet, orderNum, cosmetics, orderSts, phNum, lr,dataSource, mapped, final;
    
    
    ourName = "My Company Name";
    
    orderNum = e.namedValues["Order Number"].toString();
    
    sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("orderStatus");
    lr = sSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    
    dataSource = sSheet.getRange(2, 2, lr).getValues();
    
    mapped = dataSource.map(function(r){ 
      return r[0].toString()});
    mapped.pop();
    
    final = mapped.includes(orderNum);
    
    orderSts = sSheet.getRange(sSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
    theirMail = sSheet.getRange(sSheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue();
    theirName = sSheet.getRange(sSheet.getLastRow(),5).getValue();
    phNum = sSheet.getRange(sSheet.getLastRow(),6).getValue();    
    
    subject = "Order status notification from " + ourName + " to " + theirName;
    
    if (final == false){
        
        message = 
          "<div style='text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;'><h2>Dear <b>" + theirName +
              ",</b></h2><p>Your order no is <b><span style='font-size: 14px;'>" + orderNum +
                "</span>.</b> <b><span style='font-size: 14px;'>Your order has been processed.</span>" + 
                  "</b></p><p>We packaged your order and dropped it to the logistics. You will recieve phone call on <b><span style='font-size: 14px;'>" + phNum + 
                    "</span></b> from logistics.<br>Thanks for purchasing from <b><span style='font-size: 14px;'>" + ourName +
                      "</span></b>.</p><p>Best regards,<br><b><span style='font-size: 14px;'>"+ourName+"</span></b></p></div>"+
                        "<p style='text-align: center;'><br><b>For further information please visit our facebook page <a href='https://www.facebook.com/' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>"+ourName+"</a>.</b></p><hr />";
      
      
      textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n\n");
      
      
      cosmetics = {name: ourName, htmlBody: message};
      
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(theirMail, subject, message, cosmetics);
    }
    
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- On form submit, select the column (range) where you store all the order numbers and create a `TextFinder` and store it in a variable using the `createTextFinder(findText)` method for the specified range.
- Get the `TextFinder` from the previous step and search the order number using the `findNext()` method.
- If `findNext()` returns `null` then move to the next step. `else`, do nothing.
- Get the email address to which you plan to send the order number.
- After having the email address, use the `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` method to send the email. If you'd like, you can use HTML in the body to make it more professional.

For additional information, read:

- the [reference guide on creating TextFinders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String)),
- the [reference guide on finding text using a TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder),
- and the [reference guide on GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).

**Sample code:**

```js
// imagine you store all the order numbers in column C, starting from row 2 to the last row in the column:

var emailRecipient = test@test.com;
var ordernumber = 123;
var RangeToSearch = sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getLastRow());
var TextFinder = RangeToSearch.createTextFinder(ordernumber);
var found = TextFinder.findNext();

if (found == null) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailRecipient,
    subject: "New Order! Order Number: " + ordernumber,
    htmlBody: html
  });
}
```

Comment: Can I implement onFormSubmit trigger here? I will get my order number from Form Submission. and take that order number and search it excluding that newly submitted row. I hope you got me.